# Updating score between alternating players

Tags: python

This is the code that I've got for a game between 2 players where 2 dice are rolled and the first player to get to 50 or over wins. But instead of that, the output is an endless printing of scores without actually being updated. I know that the error is probably where I set Apos and Bpos to 1, but I don't know any other ways to solve this.

```
from itertools import cycle
import random

def turn_control():
    for current_player in cycle(["A", "B"]):
        play_game(current_player)


def play_game(current_player):
    Apos = 1
    Bpos = 1

    if current_player == "A":

        number1 = random.randint(1,6)
        number2 = random.randint(1,6)
        add = number1 + number2
        Apos = Apos + add
        print("Player A position: ", Apos)

    if Apos >= 50:
        print(current_player, " wins")



    elif current_player == "B":
        number1 = random.randint(1,6)
        number2 = random.randint(1,6)
        add = number1 + number2
        Bpos = Bpos + add
        print("Player B position: ", Bpos)

    if Bpos >= 50:
        print(current_player, " wins")


turn_control()
```

Answer (score 0):

`Apos` and `Bpos` are local variables to the function `play_game` and thus are discarded and reset after each call to `play_game`.

You need to make them global variables (preface their declarations with the `global` keyword and initialize them separately outside the function), or create some sort of state object in `turn_control` that you then pass into each invocation of `play_game` for it to update.

The `global` route might be easier for a toy example like this, but a state object is more sustainable/testable/reusable for professional programming.

#### `global` example

```
foo = 1

def increment_and_print():
    global foo
    foo += 1
    print(foo)

increment_and_print()  # prints '2'
increment_and_print()  # prints '3'
```

#### state object example

```
def repeatedly_increment_and_print():
    foo_state = {'foo': 1}
    increment_and_print(foo_state)
    increment_and_print(foo_state)

def increment_and_print(foo_state):
    foo_state['foo'] += 1
    print(foo_state['foo'])

repeatedly_increment_and_print()  # prints '2', then '3'
```

Comment: But in my code, the score is not incremented by a set number. How can you change that?

Answer (score 0):

you need to make this changes

```
from itertools import cycle
import random

Apos = 1
Bpos = 1

def turn_control():
    for current_player in cycle(["A", "B"]):
        play_game(current_player)


def play_game(current_player):
    global Apos
    global Bpos

    if current_player == "A":
        number1 = random.randint(1,6)
        number2 = random.randint(1,6)
        add = number1 + number2
        Apos = Apos + add
        print("Player A position: ", Apos)

    if Apos >= 50:
        print(current_player, " wins") 
        quit()

    elif current_player == "B":
        number1 = random.randint(1,6)
        number2 = random.randint(1,6)
        add = number1 + number2
        Bpos = Bpos + add
        print("Player B position: ", Bpos)

    if Bpos >= 50:
        print(current_player, " wins")
        quit()

turn_control()
```